# Speech Bubble with background image but here's the kicker with rounded corners

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a speech bubble that has the background in the little triangle, but the only problem is it also needs rounded corners.  I'm not entirely sure how to do this, but any hack or anything would be appreciated.

Here's what I have

HTML

```
<div class="image">
    <img class="test" src="http://fc00.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2011/322/e/2/e292b11555866aec8666ded2e63ee541-d4gl4vg.png" alt="leopard" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image {
    position:relative;
    width:340px;
    background:orange;
}
.image:before, .image:after {
    border-left: 20px solid white;
    content: "";
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
}
.image:before {
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    height: 34px;
    top: 0;
}
.image:after {
    top: 39px;
    bottom:0;
    border-top: 5px solid transparent;
}
.test {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
```

Here's a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/yL7Hg/

EDIT: If it helps I only need the top-left corner to have the radius for reasons of the way my design works.  I can get the top-right just using a border-radius on .image.

Comment: Check this out: [ShapesOfCSS](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

http://jsfiddle.net/HYgbu/

```
<div class="mask">
<img class="second" src="http://fc00.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2011/322/e/2/e292b11555866aec8666ded2e63ee541-d4gl4vg.png" alt="leopard" /></div>
```

I know its not the perfect one solution, but still it is as my first thought.

Comment: I would totally accept this answer, but my speech bubble is used hundreds of times throughout the page so loading the image twice for each one isn't going to fly.  Thanks though, I upvoted your answer. :)

Comment: @John If u have basic knowlege about Photoshop it would be much easier to do it in PS. Crop it like here i just did ->     '<img class="first" src="[http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/802/it41.png](http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/802/it41.png)" alt="leopard" />'

Comment: @John actually due to wonderful magic of caching image will be loaded only once

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Yep, true

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Hey thanks for the comment, but I just have one question, because this will go on a production site, and this part of the content is used over and over.  Will it take longer for it to load due to formatting it twice or anything?

Comment: @John doesn't make a difference. URL for the image is the same, so cached version will be used.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/

Clipping and masking using HTML5.

It has browser limitations as it uses HTML5.  But all the recent browsers support it.

Answer (score 1):

This could be achieved much easier and with standard CSS. Just set 2 DIVs, one for the arrow, the other with image as background (instead of IMG tag):

```
<div class="arrow" ></div>
<div class="test" ></div>
```

And 2 respective classes:

```
.arrow {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 
    border-right:35px solid #1E0C01; 
    float:left;
    margin-top:50px;
}

.test {
    margin-left:35px;
    width:340px;
    height: 240px;
    background-size:cover;
    background-image: url("http://fc00.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2011/322/e/2/e292b11555866aec8666ded2e63ee541-d4gl4vg.png");
```

That's it: http://jsfiddle.net/yL7Hg/5/

Comment: Sorry, in my example it's kind of hard to tell but the arrow is a continuation of the background.  So the background goes through the arrow as well.  Your answer is nice, but it is missing that feature.